# Input number, output nth letter in the alphabet

Tags: python

I'm looking for a simple way to output `z` where the input is `26`.

Is there an inbuilt function similar to `string.ascii_lowercase.index('z')` but the other way around?

Comment: More explanation is needed for this question! Which code are you working on? What have you done? Let see the full code.

Comment: why not `string.ascii_lowercase[26-1]`?

Comment: `chr(96+your_val)` for lower-case alphabets, `chr(96+26)`->`'z'` `chr(96+1)`-> `'a'`

Comment: `print(string.ascii_lowercase[25] == 'z')` check the condition and print it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
z = 26
letter = string.ascii_lowercase[z-1]
```

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase[z-1]` — `z` is not defined here